# Visual Studio Code not running python correctly in "Output", only in "Terminal"

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, terminal, output

For some weird reason, Visual Studio hasn't performed correctly what I've been doing in python. Unlike all the tutorials I find, where they normally run in the "output" field, in mine it displays correctly only in the terminal.

```
print('test','trying', sep='@')
```

Output:

```
File "/Users/x/Desktop/Livre.py", line 2

print('test','trying', sep='@')
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Terminal:

```
test@trying
```

Here is an example of the SEP command, but the same thing happens, for example, when I put special characters in lists, even when I use utf8.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

EDIT:
So, I understood what is happening, like was told in one of the answers: Visual Studio Code is using python version 2.7 in the "Output" field, for some reason, even though I have installed and reinstalled Code Runner and Python 3.10 several times.

Unfortunately so far it hasn't solved the problem.

But I haven't given up yet, and somewhere here in Stack I wiil discover how to figure it out :)

Comment: It's probably using Python 2, not 3. What extension are you using to run the script? Code Runner? Please [edit] to clarify that. If it is, then what's the *full* output? It should say which interpreter it's using. And does your script have a shebang? If not, I'd add one. I think there's also a Code Runner setting for which Python interpreter to use by default.

Comment: FYI, `sep` is a keyword argument (kwarg), not a command, and Visual Studio is not the same thing as Visual Studio Code (VS Code for short).

Answer (score 0):

Install and run the code with **[Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)**.

After installing this extension, the triangular play button in the upper right corner will have three options

[image]

Select `Run Code` to run the code, and the result will be output in the **OUTPUT** panel.

*Right-clicking directly on the editor interface and selecting `Run Code` is the same.*

[image]

*Tips:*

Among the three options, `Run Code` is provided by **Code Runner**, and the other `Run Python File` and `Debug Python File` are provided by Microsoft's official extension **[python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)**.

Comment: (unfortunately my Code Runner is still using python version 2.7, instead of 3.10, even after updating it several times, and it's python too)

Comment: What system are you using? win or mac? Can you show the environment variables of your system?